# how to add column wise data in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Here is my XML File: 
XML contains disk space information of hosts.

```
`<disk>
<host name="host1">
<partitions>
<partition>/par1</partition>
<diskUsed>60%</diskUsed>
</partitions>
<partitions>
<partition>/par2</partition>
<diskUsed>70%</diskUsed>
</partitions>
</host>
<host name="host2">
<partitions>
<partition>/par1</partition>
<diskUsed>80%</diskUsed>
</partitions>
<partitions>
<partition>/par2</partition>
<diskUsed>90%</diskUsed>
</partitions>
</host>
</disk>`
```

I want to display as below in html
I was not able to read them by column wise, can you please suggest any ways to do this?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>host1</td>
    <td>host2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>par1</td>
    <td>60%</td>
    <td>80%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>par2</td>
    <td>70%</td>
    <td>90%</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Any ideas how it can be done using XSLT?

Sorry Below is the XSL code tried. I cannot copy the code i wrote(in client env). So re-wrote it, sorry for the trouble.

```
<xsl:variable name="disks" select="disk"/>
<table id="disk">
<tr>
<xsl:foreach select="$disk">
<th><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></th>
</xsl:foreach>
</tr>
<tr>
<xsl:for-each select="$disk">
<xsl:for-each select ="partitions">
<td><xsl:value-of select="diskUsed"/></td>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

here i am not able to print the partitions name

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? Surely you're not asking for someone to write the entire thing for you from scratch?

Comment: @Andrea Please do not edit OP's code: you don't know what it looks like.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, i have added the xsl i tried.